# Set control location to original

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, location

Is there any way to set control location to original (initialize time)?
I changing location on many controls, and in some situation I must change they location to original.

Answer (score 2):

just remember the original values and reset them - so before setting your new ones to something like

```
oldX = control.X
```

if you have really a lot of controls you can to something like this

```
private Dictionary<Control, int> OldValuesX = new Dictionary<Control, int>();

public void SaveProperties()
{
   foreach (var ctr in this.Controls)
     OldValuesX[ctr] = ctr.X;
}
```

and later

```
public void ResetProperties(Control ctr)
{
   ctr.X = OldValuesX[ctr];
}
```

just extent this to your need (for example save more properties than X-Values in a Tuple, self-defined struct, etc.

Comment: I think his question is also about WHEN to save the original coordinates. That would be OnFormShown (or what is it called).

Comment: yes Form_Load would be the usual place - in any case this will only work after InitializeComponent(); because in there the controls and values are set (this is called in the constructor, so you can put the SaveProperties in there too)